# "new event" title on the modal box appering-fullcalendar jquery plugin issue

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, fullcalendar

This question is directed towards the people that use the fullcalendar jquery plugin [fullcalndar link](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)

I am using this tutorial here to make use of backbone to store events[backbone tutorial](http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/08/05/building-a-shared-calendar-with-backbone-js-and-fullcalendar-a-step-by-step-tutorial/)

Currently I am at the point where by clicking a slot in the calendar a modal pop ups titled "New Event".

And here is the problem, I want to change that to "New Appointment", since I am building an appointment system.
I have found nowhere in the code where the New Event string is created so that I can modify it.
It is not located in the HTML file though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe in this function:

```
var EventView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#eventDialog'),
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.el.dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: 'New Event',
            buttons: {'Cancel': this.close}
        });

        return this;
    },
    close: function() {
        this.el.dialog('close');
    }
});
```

Comment: yes you are right...I wonder, how I did not notice it myself.Thanks